# Fabric.io upload not working with crashlytics and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want upload my app with `Fabric.io` but she didn't show in interface.

I follow this [tutorial](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) for first time upload.

I add this in my `Build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

I add my apiKey in my `AndroidManifest`

```
<meta-data
  android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
  android:value="*"
/>
```

And I add this in my `app main`

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
}
```

I haven't error when I build with `Android Studio` but my app isn't upload

Which step did I miss ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there is a problem with Crashlytics 2.9.7 because the same problem just happened to me. You can solve it by downgrading the dependency to version 2.9.6

Comment: We run into same issue. Downgrade solved it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.9.7 have a bug with "firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" flag. New library release (2.9.8) fixes this issue.